# Method call stack in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way which I can trace which methods were called during app execution? For example, I want to see which methods from which classes were executed and in which order they were executed during a series of events.

Comment: Tag log in your apiRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, while you are debugging with breakpoints there is icon beside the variables in the debugger tab [image: frames]